# Android: Media files vanish from file system

Tags: android, file, file-io, media-player

I am stuck with a weird problem. I have an activity with a MediaPlayer that should play a just recorded audio file. At first the mediaplayer is initialized ok and  the file can be played.

When I rotate the screen, the activity is destroyed and then reinitialized for the new orientation. Therefore, I  re-initialize the mediaplayer too.

this works a couple of times, but at some point mediaPlayer.setDataSource() throws a NullPointerException because the file is suddenly gone. Sadly, I haven't seen any other error in the logs.

Here are some Code snippets:

player creation:

```
/**
 * Creates and initializes the player with the proper file.
 */
private void createPlayer() {
    synchronized (playerMutex) {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setLooping(false);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }
    readGreeting();
}
```

player initialization:

```
    isPrepared = false;
    try {
        final File file = new File(audioFilename);

        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        synchronized (playerMutex) {
            player.setDataSource(in.getFD());
        }

        // using a runnable instead of prepareAsync to not accidentally call pause on media player while preparing
        Runnable preparer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (playerMutex) {
                        if (player != null) {
                            player.prepare();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error preparing player for file " + file.getAbsolutePath(), ex);
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(preparer).start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        btnPlayback.setEnabled(false);
        Log.e(TAG, "Error preparing player", ex);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "initPlayer: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

saving instance state...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    synchronized (playerMutex) {

        if (isPlaying()) {
            getIntent().putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_SEEK, player.getCurrentPosition());
            pause();
        }
    }
    setAudioModeBackToNormal();
    super.onPause();
}

private void pause() {
    synchronized (playerMutex) {
        if (isPlaying()) {
            player.pause();
        }
    }
    btnPlayback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    outState.putBundle("extras", extras);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    getIntent().putExtras(savedInstanceState.getBundle("extras"));
}
```

cleanup:

```
private void stopPlayerAndFreeResources() {
    synchronized (playerMutex) {
        isPrepared = false;
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
            in = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm looking at the problem from the wrong angle and it has nothing to do with player. Has anybody ever had issues with disappearing files?

Comment: Is it something to do with your thread's, the last thread File() hasn't let go of read access to the file or something?

Comment: It might be something like that, but I can't find where. If you look at player initialization snippet, you see, that the file input stream is closed immediately after the call to player.setDataSource(in.getFD());

Comment: ups, wron button...I have no I

Comment: I have no idea what happens to the file descriptor, it should be cleaned up by the player when it is closed.

Comment: How is stopPlayerAndFreeResources called?

Comment: it is called both in onDestroyed() to release resources on close and onStart() to avoid conflicts right before creating and initializing a new player. It is called on other occasions but those need user interaction and don't seem to be relevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had playlist files disappear once. The cause of the problem turned out to be certain media players that had an option to manage my playlists. In this case manage meant deleting the playlists I already had :(